# ansible-playbooks - install a list of apt packages from a file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying create a Ansible playbook that will read contents of a file and use those contents to install packages on a target machine.

In simpler terms, I want to run this command converted to an ansible playbook

`cat ./meta/install-list/apt | xargs apt install -y`

---

**./meta/install-list/apt**

```
neofetch
tmux
git
```

**./ansible/playbooks/apt.yaml**

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Extract APT packages to install
    command: cat ../../meta/install-list/apt
    register: _pkgs
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true

  - name: Install APT packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ _pkgs.stdout_lines }}"
      state: latest
```

**./ansible.cfg**

```ini
[defaults]
inventory = ./ansible/inventory/hosts.yaml
```

**./ansible/inventory/hosts.yaml**

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    group-machines:
      hosts:
        target-machine.local
```

Command to run playbook

`ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass ./ansible/playbooks/apt.yaml --limit group-machine`

When running the command, it gets stuck on **`Extract APT packages to install`**

NOTE:
these files mentioned above are to be only on machine that is running the command. If possible, I'd like to prevent copying files to target machines and then running the playbooks tasks

PS: new to ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is more than enough by @Zeitounator. But if you do some formatting to your original file of package list as below

```
packages:
  - neofetch
  - tmux
  - git
```

After that you can simply run the playbook like below

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars_files: ../../meta/install-list/apt

  tasks:
  - name: Install APT packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
```

Now suppose if you are lazy enough to not want to do the formatting then below playbook also will do the trick. Its much cleaner and scalable in my opinion.

```
---
- name: SHow the packages list
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: View the packages list file
      shell: cat ../../meta/install-list/apt
      register: output


    - name: Install the package
      apt:
        name: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
        state: latest
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything in your "Extract APT packages to install" task that should cause it to get stuck... but you don't need that task in any case; you can combine your two tasks into a single task like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Install APT packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
    vars:
      packages: "{{ lookup('file', '../../meta/install-list/apt').splitlines() }}"
```

Here we're using a [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html#examples) to read the contents of a file. Lookups always run on the local (control) host.

Note that you could write the above like this as well...

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Install APT packages
    apt:
      name: "{{ lookup('file', '../../meta/install-list/apt').splitlines() }}"
      state: latest
```

...but I like to keep longer jinja expressions in `vars` in order to keep the rest of the arguments more readable.